# After DXF conversion, layer with same coordinate and projection not visible

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dxf

I've converted a DXF file to shp (using another DXF importer/convertor plugin).
In QGIS this shp will open fine if standalone but is not visible when added to a project with other shapefiles.
The xy coordinates are comparable points are the same, as is the CRS.
I've tried various options with no success - any thoughts on the cause?

Comment: Why convert to shp, when you can load the dxf directly?

Comment: Can you see each layer when zooming to layers (by "right click" > "Zoom to layer")  separately?

Comment: No, qgis crashes